# Custom Hotkeys for Starcraft 2

Tags: starcraft-2

In the Hotkeys options, I see presets but there's no way to make my own preset.

Is there anyway to do this in Starcraft 2?

Thanks for any info :)

**Note:** I play Starcraft 2 on OS X

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blizzard has meanwhile introduced an in-game hotkey editor that allows you to change all keys and even have several different hotkey profiles. It can be found in the options menu listed as 'Hotkeys'.

There are multiple templates to choose from such as for example grid and standard, which can be used as a starting point to personalize the hotkeys.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: I did find this thread on the forums, you might check it out.  Haven't tried it myself (am fine with the defaults)

http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/forum/topic/144854484

<strike>This is not currently possible from the StarCraft 2 client.  I have heard of some people remapping their keys from the OS side before starting the game, but to me it'd just be easier to learn the hotkeys.</strike>

You do, however, have the option of using Grid layout on the hotkeys, but you cannot specify your own.

Comment: MPQ editor is for Windows only :(